# Subsetting a dataframe by date ranges

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to separate a dataframe by date ranges in an efficient way, so far I have only come up with:

```
mask0 = df['Date of survey'].between('2010-01-01', '2010-12-31')
mask1 = df['Date of survey'].between('2011-01-01', '2011-12-31')
mask2 = df['Date of survey'].between('2012-01-01', '2012-12-31')

...
maskn = df['Date of survey'].between('nnnn-01-01', 'nnnn-12-31')
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! 
(I'd be using the masks to subset the dataframe and get the mean sums of each column variable for each year).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better here is use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by years with aggregate functions like `mean` and `sum`:

```
df1 = df.resample('A', on='Date of survey').agg(['mean','sum'])
```

Or use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by years by [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html):

```
df2 = df.groupby(df['Date of survey'].dt.year).agg(['mean','sum'])
```